# How to have double counter variable in Python loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, counter, alternate

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,7,8,9,10]
for a,b in x,y:
    print(a,b)
```

expected output:

```
1,6
2,7
3,8
4,9
5,10
```

But I know two count variables are not possible. Help me by giving better alternative code to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` here.

```
for a,b in zip(x,y):
    print(a,b,sep=', ')
```

Using `range`

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i],y[i],sep=', ')
```

If you have unequal length list use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```
for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(x,y,fillvalues=' '):
    print(i,j,sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `zip()` function. The `zip()` function returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator are paired together etc.

Try this:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5] 
y=[6,7,8,9,10]

for a, b in zip(x, y):
    print(f"{a}, {b}")
```

**Output:**

```
1, 6
2, 7
3, 8
4, 9
5, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use zip and format the output:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

str_ = ""
for x_, y_ in zip(x,y):
    str_ += "%d,%d " % (x_, y_)

print(str_)
```

**Output:**

```
1,6 2,7 3,8 4,9 5,10
```

Also:

```
for x_, y_ in zip(x,y):
    print("%d,%d" % (x_, y_))
```

**Output:**

```
1,6
2,7
3,8
4,9
5,10
```